# Finding the size of a list that's too big for memory?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Brand new Haskell programmer here.  Just finished "Learn you a Haskell"...  I'm interested in how large a set is that has some particular properties. I have working code for some small parameter values, but I'd like to know how to deal with larger structures.  I know Haskell can do "infinite data structures" but I'm just not seeing how to get there from where I'm at and Learn You a Haskell / Google isn't getting me over this.

Here's the working code for my `eSet` given "small" arguments `r` and `t`

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
import System.Exit

myPred :: [Int] -> Bool
myPred a = myPred' [] a
    where
        myPred' [] []         = False
        myPred' [] [0]        = True
        myPred' _  []         = True
        myPred' acc (0:aTail) = myPred' acc aTail
        myPred' acc (a:aTail)
             | a `elem` acc   = False
             | otherwise      = myPred' (a:acc) aTail

superSet :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
superSet r t = replicateM r [0..t]

eSet :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
eSet r t = filter myPred $ superSet r t

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        [rArg, tArg] ->
            print $ length $ eSet (read rArg) (read tArg)
        [rArg, tArg, "set"] ->
            print $          eSet (read rArg) (read tArg)
        _ ->
            die "Usage: eSet r r set <set optional for printing set itself otherwise just print the size
```

When compiled/run I get

```
$ ghc eSet.hs -rtsopts
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( eSet.hs, eSet.o )
Linking eSet ...
$ # Here's is a tiny eSet to illustrate.  It is the set of lists of r integers from zero to t with no repeated nonzero list entries
$ ./eSet 4 2 set
[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,2],[0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,2],[0,1,2,0],[0,2,0,0],[0,2,0,1],[0,2,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,2],[1,0,2,0],[1,2,0,0],[2,0,0,0],[2,0,0,1],[2,0,1,0],[2,1,0,0]]
$ ./eSet 8 4 +RTS -sstderr
3393
     174,406,136 bytes allocated in the heap
      29,061,152 bytes copied during GC
       4,382,568 bytes maximum residency (7 sample(s))
         148,664 bytes maximum slop
              14 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       328 colls,     0 par    0.047s   0.047s     0.0001s    0.0009s
  Gen  1         7 colls,     0 par    0.055s   0.055s     0.0079s    0.0147s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.298s  (  0.301s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.102s  (  0.102s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.406s  (  0.405s elapsed)

  %GC     time      25.1%  (25.2% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    585,308,888 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  74.8% of total user, 75.0% of total elapsed

$ ./eSet 10 5 +RTS -sstderr
63591
  27,478,010,744 bytes allocated in the heap
   4,638,903,384 bytes copied during GC
     532,163,096 bytes maximum residency (15 sample(s))
      16,500,072 bytes maximum slop
            1556 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     52656 colls,     0 par    6.865s   6.864s     0.0001s    0.0055s
  Gen  1        15 colls,     0 par    8.853s   8.997s     0.5998s    1.8617s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time   52.652s  ( 52.796s elapsed)
  GC      time   15.717s  ( 15.861s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.193s  (  0.211s elapsed)
  Total   time   68.564s  ( 68.868s elapsed)

  %GC     time      22.9%  (23.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    521,883,277 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  77.1% of total user, 76.7% of total elapsed
```

I see my memory usage is very high and there's a lot of garbage collecting.  When running `eSet 12 6` I get a Segmentation fault.

I feel like `filter myPred $ superSet r t` is keeping me from lazily making the subset one part at a time so I can deal with much larger (but finite) sets, but I don't know how to change to another approach that would do that.  I think that's the root of my question.

Also, as this is my first Haskell program, points on style and how to achieve the Haskell analog of "pythonic" are much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it does not matter here, but before measuring any performance remember to turn on optimization compiling with `-O2` or something similar. Sometimes it makes a huge difference.

Comment: If you only care about how many there are, a bit of combinatorics should get you where you want to go much more cheaply. I'd be happy to write a second answer about that if it sounds interesting to you.

Comment: @DanielWagner A bit of combinatorics would be most welcome, and a nice way to help confirm the program's correctness!  Please do write it up.

Comment: Okay, I've written about how the combinatorics approach can lead us to a pretty definition for `eSet` that is faster and less memory-intensive than your proposal, and doesn't need sneaky tricks to avoid GHC optimizations like my first answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A completely alternate approach is to just do a little bit of combinatorics analysis. Here's the process that `eSet r t` does, as near as I can make out:

1. Choose at most `r` elements without replacement from a set of size `t`.
2. Pad the sequence to a length of `r` by interleaving a sentinel value.

So let's just count the ways of doing each of these steps, rather than actually performing them. We'll introduce a new parameter, `s`, which is the length of the sequence produced by step (1) (and which we therefore know has `s <= r` and `s <= t`). How many sequences of size `s` are there when drawing elements without replacement from a set of size `t`? Well, there are `t` choices for the first element, `t-1` choices for the second element, `t-2` choices for the third element, ...

```
-- sequencesWithoutReplacement is a very long name!
seqWORepSize :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
seqWORepSize s t = product [t-s+1 .. t]
```

Then we want to pad the sequence out to a length of `r`. We're going to choose `s` positions in the `r`-long sequence to be drawn from our sequence, and the remainder will be sentinels. How many ways are there to do that? This one is a well-known combinatorics operator called `choose`.

```
choose :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
choose r s = product [r-s+1 .. r] `div` product [2 .. s]
```

The number of ways to produce a padded sequence of a given length is just the product of these two numbers, since the choices of "what values to insert" and "where to insert values" can be made completely independently.

```
paddedSeqSize :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
paddedSeqSize r s t = seqWORepSize s t * (r `choose` s)
```

And now we're pretty much done. Just iterate over all possible sequence lengths and add up the `paddedSeqSize`.

```
eSetSize :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
eSetSize r t = sum $ map (\s -> paddedSeqSize r s t) [0..r]
```

We can try it out in ghci:

```
> :set +s
> map length $ [eSet 1 1, eSet 4 4, eSet 6 4, eSet 4 6]
[2,209,1045,1045]
(0.13 secs, 26,924,264 bytes)
> [eSetSize 1 1, eSetSize 4 4, eSetSize 6 4, eSetSize 4 6]
[2,209,1045,1045]
(0.01 secs, 120,272 bytes)
```

This way is significantly faster and significantly more memory-friendly. Indeed, we can make queries and get answers about `eSet`s that we would never be able to count the size of one-by-one, e.g.

```
> length . show $ eSetSize 1000 1000
2594
(0.26 secs, 909,746,448 bytes)
```

Good luck counting to 10^2594 one at a time. =P

**Edit**
This idea can also be adapted to produce the padded sequences themselves rather than just counting how many there are. First, a handy utility that I find myself defining over and over for picking out individual elements of a list and reporting on the leftovers:

```
zippers :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
zippers = go [] where
    go ls [] = []
    go ls (h:rs) = (ls, h, rs) : go (h:ls) rs
```

Now, the sequences without replacement can be done by repeatedly choosing a single element from the leftovers.

```
seqWORep :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
seqWORep 0 _  = [[]]
seqWORep n xs = do
    (ls, y, rs) <- zippers xs
    ys <- seqWORep (n-1) (ls++rs)
    return (y:ys)
```

Once we have a sequence, we can pad it to a desired size by producing all the interleavings of the sentinel value as follows:

```
interleavings :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [[a]]
interleavings 0 _ xs = [xs]
interleavings n z [] = [replicate n z]
interleavings n z xs@(x:xt) =  map (z:) (interleavings (n-1) z xs)
                            ++ map (x:) (interleavings  n    z xt)
```

And finally, the top-level function just delegates to `seqWORep` and `interleavings`.

```
eSet :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
eSet r t = do
    s <- [0..r]
    xs <- seqWORep s [1..t]
    interleavings (r-s) 0 xs
```

In my tests this modified `eSet` has nice flat memory usage both with and without optimizations; does not generate any spurious elements that need to be later `filter`ed out, and so is faster than your original proposal; and to me looks like quite a natural definition compared to the answer that relies on tricking GHC. A nice collection of properties!

Comment: Impressive.  This eSet 10 5 runs in 0.527s elapsed vs 0.766s elapsed for my solution with: 
eSet r t = return [] >>= foldr (<=<) return (replicate r (branch t)) 
and it has very nice properties (no filtering, works with -O2, and fast).  Excellent application of domain specific know-how.  Thank you!  Well done!

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the culprit here is `replicateM`, which has [this implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#replicateM):

```
replicateM cnt0 f =
    loop cnt0
  where
    loop cnt
        | cnt <= 0  = pure []
        | otherwise = liftA2 (:) f (loop (cnt - 1))
```

The problem line is `liftA2 (:) f (loop (cnt - 1))`; probably `loop (cnt - 1)` is getting shared among all the calls to `(:)` partially applied to elements of `f`, and so `loop (cnt - 1)` must be kept in memory. Unfortunately `loop (cnt - 1)` is quite a long list...

It can be a bit fiddly to convince GHC *not* to share something. The following redefinition of `superSet` gives me a nice flat memory usage; it will probably be a bit slower on examples that do fit in memory, of course. The key idea is to make it look to the untrained eye (i.e. GHC) like the recursive monadic action depends on the choices made earlier, even though it doesn't.

```
superSet :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
superSet r t = go r 0 where
    go 0 ignored = if ignored == 0 then [[]] else [[]]
    go r ignored = do
        x <- [0..t]
        xs <- go (r-1) (ignored+x)
        return (x:xs)
```

If you don't mind avoiding optimizations, the more natural definition also works:

```
superSet 0 t = [[]]
superSet r t = do
    x <- [0..t]
    xs <- superSet (r-1) t
    return (x:xs)
```

...but with `-O2` GHC is too clever and notices that it can share the recursive call.

Comment: Is the `ignored+h` supposed to be `ignored+1` or something?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Oops, it's supposed to be `ignored+x`. My test file used `h` and `t` instead of `x` and `xs` but I found the overloading of `t` a bit confusing when doing the writeup and incompletely changed the names. Fix incoming; thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading parts of [LYaH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) and thinking about @daniel-wagners answer monadically composing sounded like it would be worthwhile to try again.  The new code total memory is flat and works with and without the `-O2` optimization.

Source:

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
import System.Exit

allowed :: [Int] -> Bool
allowed a = allowed' [] a
    where
        allowed' [ ] [ ]       = False
        allowed' [ ] [0]       = True
        allowed'  _  [ ]       = True
        allowed' acc (0:aTail) = allowed' acc aTail
        allowed' acc (a:aTail)
             | a `elem` acc    = False
             | otherwise       = allowed' (a:acc) aTail

branch :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
branch t x  = filter allowed [n:x | n <- [0..t]]

eSet :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
eSet r t = return [] >>= foldr (<=<) return (replicate r (branch t))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        [rArg, tArg] ->
            print $ length $ eSet (read rArg) (read tArg)
        [rArg, tArg, "set"] ->
            print $          eSet (read rArg) (read tArg)
        _ -> die "Usage: eSet r r set <set optional>"
```

The version with monadic function composition tests much faster and without the memory issues...

```
$ ./eSetMonad 10 5 +RTS -sstderr
63591
 289,726,000 bytes allocated in the heap
     997,968 bytes copied during GC
      63,360 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
      24,704 bytes maximum slop
           2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                 Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0       553 colls,     0 par    0.008s   0.008s     0.0000s    0.0002s
Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0002s    0.0003s

INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.426s  (  0.429s elapsed)
GC      time    0.009s  (  0.009s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
Total   time    0.439s  (  0.438s elapsed)

%GC     time       2.0%  (2.0% elapsed)

Alloc rate    680,079,893 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  98.0% of total user, 98.3% of total elapsed
```